# Length of a curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

[image]

I know how to find arc length and set up the equation in normal circumstances, but I have failed in all attempts to even set up this problem. I cannot even find a good example similar to this to get me on the right track. How would I go about solving it?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is *quite* a nice problem insofar as it tests so many skills: how to set up an arc-length problem, dummy-variables and variable switching, the good ol' FToC and then a decently tricky integral.

Comment: Yeah it's been giving me a headache for some time

Comment: So, I guess one hint: what if you'd had this problem with all the $x$'s and $y$'s switched?

Comment: Conveniently, if one is short of paper, one can find the answer without any writing.

Comment: Um, I honestly have no clue Im sorry if I sound stupid..

Comment: Integrate $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}$. For $\frac{dx}{dy}$ use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Which, for sake of clarity, is the "hint" I was providing below.

Comment: Okay thank you, both of you.

Comment: Okay so I'm very sorry to bother you, how would I even do that integration. Would I substitute t for y and integrate?

Comment: Sorry I meant y for t

Comment: You don't **do** the integration, you are finding the derivative of it with respect to $y$. For that, you substitute $y$ for $t$ (FTC). Square. Add $1$. You get something simple. Take the square root. You get something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In order to compute the arc length, you set up an integral of the form $\int ds=\int \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}.$ The 'usual' route is to say that $y=f(x)$, then find $dy/dx$ and use this to obtain an integral with respect to $x$. That's not practical here, but do you see a convenient alternative?

One thing that may clarify the problem's intention: you're given $x$ as a function of $y$ in the form of a definite integral. So you do have a curve, just not given explicitly.

Comment: So you mean that instead of "dx^2+dy^2" I could possibly do 2sec^4t as dx^2 and 1 as dy^2?

Comment: Not _quite_, though nearly: you'll still need differentials in that statement, for one, and for $dx^2$ you've stated it incorrectly.

Comment: I'm lost, I kind of get what you mean but cannot get out of my boxed mind I guess.

Comment: @Jerry: Andre's comments to the question are what I was hinting you towards.

Comment: Okay sick thank you very much

Comment: Okay so I'm very sorry to bother you, how would I even do that integration. Would I substitute y for t and integrate?